I am trying to scrape some information from tinder and I keep getting StaleElementReferenceException
I am trying to scrape 5 images, username and bio from tinder and I keep getting this error even though i the element i am using is present in the DOM
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found in the current frame
this is my code
links = set()

containers = WebDriverWait(driver, 
31).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 
'StretchedBox')))
 mini_container = containers.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="c-1086086869"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/main/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/div/div[1]/div[1]/div')

print(f"Found {len(mini_container)} mini containers")

for container in mini_container:
    tags = container.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'div')
    print(f"Found {len(tags)} tags in container")
    for tag in tags:
        style = tag.get_attribute('style')
        print(f"Tag style attribute: {style}")
        match = re.search(r'url\("(.+?)"\)', style)
        if match:
            link = match.group(1)
            links.add(link)
            print(f"Extracted link: {link}")


You should read this: https://reflect.run/articles/how-to-deal-with-staleelementreferenceexception-in-selenium/

This is only a part of your code.

probably means that while you are iterating a reference array (either mini_container, or tags) the DOM has updated.  This can happen if you get the array while DOM is in the process of updating, or doing an action that would cause a DOM update while iterating the array.   You need to catch that exception and re-get the reference array(s).
